# Can I use SIFT feature detector other than images?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

I know how to use SIFT algorithm for images but I never use it for other kinds of data. I have RGBD data (x,y,z,time) where x,y,z is the joint position along x,y,z coordinates. Now can I use SIFT algorithm to this data to find features that will act as input to traditional machine learning algorithms like SVM, DT etc?